# T-SQL CREATE DATABASE combining COLLATE and FILESPEC(s)

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Per the docs at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-database-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017 it would *appear* possible to author a single T-SQL `CREATE DATABASE` command which includes both > 0 filespecs *and* other e.g., `COLLATE`, `CONTAINMENT` directive(s).

Either by themselves *is* possible/acceptable/successful, e.g.,

```
CREATE DATABASE test01 ON PRIMARY (NAME=file1, FILENAME='/var/opts/mssql/data/file1.mdf', SIZE=100MB)
```

...and...

```
CREATE DATABASE test01 CONTAINMENT=NONE COLLATE French_CI_AI
```

...are both acceptable.

However, neither this...

```
CREATE DATABASE test01 CONTAINMENT=NONE COLLATE French_CI_AI ON PRIMARY (NAME=file1, FILENAME='/var/opts/mssql/data/file1.mdf', SIZE=100MB)
```

...nor this...

```
CREATE DATABASE test01 ON PRIMARY (NAME=file1, FILENAME='/var/opts/mssql/data/file1.mdf', SIZE=100MB) CONTAINMENT=NONE COLLATE French_CI_AI
```

...are seemingly valid T-SQL (both are rejected by the MSSQL server as syntax errors).

Is there a syntactical way to combine all of these into a single T-SQL `CREATE DATABASE` command as the docs imply?  Or am I misreading the SYNTAX section of that referenced doc and this isn't supported as a single command?

Comment: DBAs cheat. Use SSMS to create the new database, set all the options and click on the `Script` button at the top toolbar instead of `OK`

Comment: The top part of the syntax section of the document you linked to shows `CREATE ... CONTAINMENT ... ON ... COLLATE ...`. Why did you think `CONTAINMENT ... COLLATE ...` was required to appear together?

Comment: Adding to @Damien_The_Unbeliever, comment, try `CREATE DATABASE test01 CONTAINMENT=NONE ON PRIMARY (NAME=file1, FILENAME='/var/opts/mssql/data/file1.mdf', SIZE=100MB) COLLATE French_CI_AI ;`

Comment: @DanGuzman that worked-- thx.  Your suggestion of placing the COLLATE after the filespec(s) with the CONTAINMENT preceding the filespec(s) worked perfectly; if you post this comment as an answer I'm happy to accept it as such so that you get credit...!

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos That's a great point -- thx, will attempt that next time to short-circuit this!

Answer (score 2):

The excerpt below from the doc link in your question shows the required order of clauses in the `CREATE DATABASE` statement:

```
CREATE DATABASE database_name
[ CONTAINMENT = { NONE | PARTIAL } ]
[ ON
      [ PRIMARY ] <filespec> [ ,...n ]
      [ , <filegroup> [ ,...n ] ]
      [ LOG ON <filespec> [ ,...n ] ]
]
[ COLLATE collation_name ]
[ WITH <option> [,...n ] ]
[;]
```

To adhere to this syntax, specify the containment option immediately after the database name and include the collation specification after the filegroups/files:

```
CREATE DATABASE test01
CONTAINMENT=NONE
ON PRIMARY (NAME=file1, FILENAME='/var/opts/mssql/data/file1.mdf', SIZE=100MB)
COLLATE French_CI_AI;
```